# Destructor delete wrong element

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a small problem with my textures.

I want that:

- m_texture has the Texture with id #5
- The Texture with ID #5 should **NOT** be deleted.

**The problem**: At the moment Texture #5 is deleted.

The Texture deleted itself in the destructor.

```
inline void SetTexture(Texture texture) //texture -> #5, m_texture -> #7
{ 
    m_texture = texture;
    //m_texture -> #5
    //texture -> #5
    // But #5 is deleted, and I don't want that
}
```

[...]

```
private:
    Texture m_texture;
```

**Edit:**

This works:

```
Texture texture(0, 102, 153);
rect.SetTexture(texture);
```

But this doesn't:

```
rect.SetTexture(Texture(0, 102, 153));
```

**Edit 2:**
I think the question will be closed, because it is to much code. [I am sorry]

Texture header:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(const std::string& fileName);
    Texture(int red, int green, int blue);

    void Bind();
    virtual ~Texture();

protected:
private:

    void Init(unsigned char* imageData, int width, int height);
    GLuint m_texture;

};
```

Texture class:

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string& fileName)
{
    int width, height, numComponents;
    unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load((fileName).c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);

    if (imageData == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Texture loading failed for texture: " << fileName << std::endl;

    Init(imageData, width, height);

    stbi_image_free(imageData);
}
Texture::Texture(int red, int green, int blue)
{
    unsigned char imageData[] = {
        static_cast<char>(red),
        static_cast<char>(green),
        static_cast<char>(blue)
    };

    Init(imageData, 1, 1);
}

void Texture::Init(unsigned char* imageData, int width, int height) {
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &m_texture);
}

void Texture::Bind()
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
}
```

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is not understandable?

Comment: As a possible hint about your problem though: Do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: You most likely want to implement *move semantics* for your textures.

Comment: @Jodocus, No, I want the texture in m_texture to be transferred without calling the destructor.

Comment: Sounds like `texture` and `m_texture` should be `std::shared_ptr<Texture>` smart pointers.

Comment: @FreddyC. That's the point of moving. The destructor will be called, but its call will have no effect.

Comment: @Jodocus Ok sorry, and how I realize that?

Comment: @FreddyC. Please research this on your own. Use a search engine!

Comment: @Jodocus It doesn't works with std::shared_ptr<Texture> and it does not reach my goal if you downvoted my question.

Comment: @FreddyC. I said nothing about `shared_ptr`, I said *move semantics*. "It doesn't work" just means you did it wrong. You need a move constructor. As for the votes: they are not meant to help you, they are indications how useful your question is for others.

Comment: @Jodocus But, also if I use a move constructor the destructor is called for #7 and not for #5.

Comment: Well, without any idea how you have defined `Texture`, how could we can help? So as written. your question is useless and only worth downvotes...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your bug is in how you are assigning IDs to `Texture`s.

Since you are having deletion during destructions there must be pointers somewhere that you have not shared in your post.

The texture object is probably not following the [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

> If you have a copy, an assignment, or a destructor then you need to make all three.

---

A walk through a what your code is currently doing:

```
inline void SetTexture(Texture texture) //Texture::Texture(Texture) is called
{ 
    m_texture = texture; //Texture::operator= is called
} //Texture::~Texture() is called
```

The ideal behavior is:

1. The ID in `texture` should be same as the one passed as a parameter.
2. That ID should be passed to `m_texture`.
3. When `texture` is destroyed it is not the only reference to the ID, and so does not destroy it.

This is the inteaded use of [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a bit. Now I have changed my question, with the new findings.

Comment: We need to see the inside of the `Texture` class.

Comment: Better call it "rule of three/five/zero", with emphasis on *zero*

Comment: Sorry I am a c++ beginner, and I don't understand this rule. I implemented the new constructors and operators and it still doesn't work.